# ToString() & Contains() have no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I have an action which returns JSON to a jQuery [datatable](http://datatables.net). The data returned can be filtered depending on the params passed to it. Here's the code:

```
public ActionResult IndexAjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel parameters) {
    var data = _mailingListRep.GetAllWithinAccount();
    IEnumerable<MailingList> filtered;

    // Filtering - THIS DOES NOT WORK!
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.sSearch)) {
        filtered = data.Where(c => 
            c.MailingListName.Contains(parameters.sSearch) ||
            ((c.IsDoubleOptIn) ? "Yes" : "No").Contains(parameters.sSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            c.Created.ToString("dd MMM yyyy").Contains(parameters.sSearch) ||
            c.ActiveMembers.Count().ToString().Contains(parameters.sSearch) ||
        c.AvailableSegments.Count().ToString().Contains(parameters.sSearch)
        );
    }
    else {
        filtered = data;
    }

    // create json object
    // return;
}
```

The problem is this gives me the following error:

> Method 'Boolean Contains(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)' has no supported translation to SQL.

### **BUT**

In the same controller is another action which also returns JSON to a datatable, which uses **the exact same filtering method** and it works fine!

```
public ActionResult ViewDeletedAjaxHandler(int id, jQueryDataTableParamModel parameters) {
    var list = _mailingListRep.GetByIDWithinAccount(id);
    var data = list.DeletedMembers;
    IEnumerable<MailingListMember> filtered;

    // Filtering - THIS WORKS, NO ERRORS!
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.sSearch)) {
        filtered = data.Where(c => 
            c.EmailAddress.Contains(parameters.sSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            c.UnsubscribedDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy").Contains(parameters.sSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        );
    }
    else {
        filtered = data;
    }

    // create json object
    // return;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is?

For reference, `Contains(string, comparison)` is an extension method:

```
public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp) {
    return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}
```

I understand what the error means, it is the fact that the code works in 1 action, but not the other than has me completely confused.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: what's the **runtime** type of data in thos two cases?

Comment: Is `data` in your second example `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`?

Comment: In both cases they are `IEnumerable<>` the first is `IEnumerable<MailingList>`, the second `IEnumerable<MailingListMember>`

Comment: I've updated the code of the second example to make the differences clearer

Comment: The compile time type doesn't matter it's the runtime type that matters (and the runtime type is always a concrete type and never an interface)

Comment: Ah ok, how do I find that out?

Comment: You set a breakpoint an inspect the object in the watch window or locals window

Comment: it's the runtime type of the collection (the this parameter to Where) you are looking for. So in your case it's data. I've updated my answer with an example

Comment: Runtime type is: System.Linq.IQueryable<PCCMS.Core.Model.MailingList>

Comment: if you expand the node you can get to the concrete type. The runtime type is **always** a concrete type since you can't instantiate an object of an interface but only a concrete class

Comment: @RuneFS Many thanks for your help - I never knew Linq would change types at runtime, however Klaus's answer was correct and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first filter that does not work is applied to a `IQueryable<T>` and your second that works is applied to an `IEnumerable<T>`.
When applied to an `IQueryable<T>`, the filter must be translateable to SQL, whereas when it is used on an `IEnumerable<T>` the filter is evaluated in memory.

To make the first one work, you need to either call `ToList()` to force the results into memory **before** applying the filter, or use the helper methods available from the [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) class.

Comment: I'm sure what you are trying to say is correct but it's incorrect that the first has to be `IQueryable<T>` it's not the compile time type that matters but the runtime type that matters. They might both have the compile time type of `IEnumerable<T>` and one of them might still use linq2sql and the other linq2object

Comment: @RuneFS I'm not saying that the compile time type **has to** be `IQueryable<T>`, I'm just saying that the runtime type **must be** `IQueryable<T>` for the code to exert that behavior. So I'm not really sure I'm getting your point.

Comment: Since the runtime type **cannot** be `IQueryable<T>` "I'm just saying that the runtime type must be `IQueryable<T>`" makes little sense. The runtime type is **always** a concrete class and **never** an interface. How would do `new IQueryable<T>()` because unless you are able to pull that off you will not have a runtime type of `IQueryable<T>()`

Comment: @RuneFS I meant **must be**, like in "The lake is freezing, the temperature must be 0 or below". And when referring to a runtime type of `IQueryable<T>` I obviously meant some type that implements `IQueryable<T>` and not **only** implements `IEnumerable<T>`. But if you feel that I could have been more concise, you are free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could have this is if the **runtime** type of the data reference is different in those two scenarios.

E.g. if they both have the compile time type `IEnumerable<T>` but one has a runtime type that makes the LINQ into a LINQ2SQL and the other makes it into a LINQ2Object. Contains works in the latter but not the former

```
IEnumerable<Entity> data = db.GetMyLazilyEvaluatedListOfEntities();
//this will fail
data.Where(e => e.Foo.Contains("bar"));
data = new List<Entity>();
//this will work
data.Where(e => e.Foo.Contains("bar"));
```

where `db.GetMyLazilyEvaluatedListOfEntities` returns an object that implements `IQueryable<Entity>` that when evaluated will be translated into SQL

you can avoid the runtime exception if you call `data.ToList()` before the where. However this will fetch the entire table from the database and do the filtering in memory. If the table is with fewish rows that should be too much of a concern but if you expect a large number of records in the database table backing data you should rewrite into something that can be translated into SQL